# How can I use VS Code to write my scripts while sending commands to RStudio?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, rstudio

RStudio is great on most fronts, but for writing scripts I prefer VS Code.
I would like to combine the best of both worlds and send R commands from VS Code to RStudio, so I can still benefit from the many useful features RStudio environment.

I have this kind of setup in Stata (using stataRun extension in VS Code) and I love it---to the point that it is hampering my transition into R.

I am hoping someone has a solution I could not find!

Cheers

Comment: if vscode doesn't have an rstudio extension, you can't.

Comment: I see. It does not. I guess my best option is to make the best out of RStudio's text editor. I read it has a Vim mode, which might help. Thanks

Comment: @Marti I assume you have seen [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/r)? As you know, RStudio is "just" an IDE around R. So if you don't like RStudio for its editing & code management capabilities, I suggest using the R extension to directly interact with the R terminal through VSCode.

Comment: Is anyone aware of VS Code extensions that allow sending commands to RStudio from VS Code? There might be but new and not easy to find.

Comment: @MauritisEvers thank you. I am aware of that. I appreciate your help but your answer does not address the issue I raised.

Comment: @Marti My comment (not answer!) was trying to explain why an extension VSCode > RStudio doesn't make much sense; an extension VSCode > R does & exists. This is like asking for an extension to send code backward and forward from VSCode to Eclipse. Decide on an IDE for writing & managing code in R: either use RStudio or VSCode.

Comment: What useful features in RStudio are you missing that aren't in VSCode?

Comment: Sorry, late reply. Probably, the only main---but huge---difference is the quality of the View( ) mode. In Rstudio it works very well and it is crucial for me to look at my data like that. In VScode, the feature is there but it's not very good yet. To me it is a deal-breaker. Would love to swap to VScode for R too once that improves, though.